# Vue app with Node backend doesn't render anything except the home page on Windows localhost, works in production and MacOS localhost

Tags: node.js, vue.js, windows-10, localhost

The app has been running successfully in production for a year, and works perfectly on MacOS localhost. Recently needed to set up the app to run on Windows 10 localhost, and after resolving all the errors, now the app boots up, requests seem to get through, however, only the '/' page actually renders, all the other routes don't render and stay at a blank page.

What could be a reason?

During initial setup, I ran into an issue with windows-build-tools and a missing Python, which I ended up eventually resolving by installing everything through Chocolatey. Could this be related?

Node version on Windows is newer than one specified in project, could this cause this?

I'm happy to provide more details and perform any experiments any of you recommend or suggest. My own guess is that it is either something related to setup on Windows or some issue with the packages on Windows.

The app is booted up through a `package.json` start script:

```json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "run-p dev:server dev:client",
  "dev:server": "nodemon --ignore './client' app.js",
  "dev:client": "cd client && npm run serve",
  "postinstall": "npm install --only=dev --prefix client && npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client",
  "start": "node app.js",
  "heroku-prebuild": "python cleanup_script.py"
},
```

The vue app contains the following script that will be executed as a result:

```json
"scripts": {
  "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
  "build": "vue-cli-service build",
  "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
  "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer --port 4200 dist/stats.json"
},
```

VueJS package.json dependencies and dev dependencies.

```json
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
  "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
  "build": "vue-cli-service build",
  "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
  "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer --port 4200 dist/stats.json"
},
"dependencies": {
  "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document": "^18.0.0",
  "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue": "^1.0.3",
  "@johmun/vue-tags-input": "^2.1.0",
  "@vue/composition-api": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
  "autolinker": "^3.14.2",
  "axios": "^0.21.1",
  "core-js": "^3.8.2",
  "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
  "detectrtc": "^1.4.1",
  "gsap": "^3.6.0",
  "imagekitio-vue": "^1.0.9",
  "ismobilejs": "^1.1.1",
  "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
  "maxlength-contenteditable": "^1.0.1",
  "socket.io-client": "^3.1.2",
  "twilio-video": "^2.10.0",
  "v-hotkey": "^0.8.0",
  "vue": "^2.6.12",
  "vue-color": "^2.8.1",
  "vue-gtag": "^1.16.1",
  "vue-i18n": "^8.22.4",
  "vue-infinite-loading": "^2.4.5",
  "vue-router": "^3.4.9",
  "vue-select": "^3.11.2",
  "vue-smooth-dnd": "^0.8.1",
  "vue-vimeo-player": "^0.2.2",
  "vue-window-size": "^1.0.3",
  "vue-youtube": "^1.4.0",
  "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.6.2",
  "vuex": "^3.6.0",
  "webrtc-adapter-test": "^0.2.10"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.3.0",
  "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.3.0",
  "@vue/cli-service": "~4.3.0",
  "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
  "dotenv-webpack": "^5.1.0",
  "eslint": "^6.7.2",
  "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
  "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.4.0"
},
"eslintConfig": {
  "root": true,
  "env": {
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:vue/essential",
    "eslint:recommended"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint"
  },
  "rules": {}
},
"browserslist": [
  "> 1%",
  "last 2 versions",
  "not dead"
]
```

Comment: Hi Phil! I start it from VS Code, both apps are in the same core folder and I've package.json start script that executes nodemon app.js to run the server app and npm run serve to run the client app. The server starts on port 3000, client on port 8080. Is this what you meant?

Comment: It's a package.json script that runs after calling npm run dev from the console. 'dev' will run the following: "run-p dev:server dev:client" and from thereon additionally: "dev:server": "nodemon --ignore './client' app.js" and "dev:client": "cd client && npm run serve". Thanks Phil!

Comment: Yes, node and windows-build-tools could be a problem. That you needed build tools means there's binary dep that is potentially incompatible with your node. Try to match node version with old one and setup the project from scratch. "all the other routes don't render and stay at a blank page" - are there errors in console and network?

Comment: Hi Estus, I will try out rebuilding all from scratch with a different Node version matching the original one. And that is the strangest part, that I've found no errors, and it seems Vue also does not provide a specific 'debug' mode as far as I've looked around? And it seems the backend works right, so I'm guessing it must be a Vue issue.

One recent update however is that I got another similar project working locally, however its setup is less complex. I'm testing if it's any specific package that could be causing the issue somehow, so far without success.

Comment: @robertfoenix Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: @EstusFlask, downgrading the Node version and starting completely blank with no changes worked!!! I tried this before as well, but I think I had changed a few things and had some other wrong Windows setups that I had cleared up by now. Thank you so much! Feel free to post an answer about this and I'll be happy to reward the bounty to you! Could you elaborate more on the relationship between needing build tools and how that translates to a dependency being incompatible with Node, or where I could learn more about it? In any case, thank you so so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node version could be a problem. That windows-build-tools is required for the installation indicates there's binary dependency that is potentially incompatible with current Node version. Binary NPM dependencies usually provide a subset of precompiled binaries for a specific package version, where a combination of platform and Node.js version that can be considered safe or supported. For any other combination, binary package needs to be compiled for current platform with build tools. This doesn't always mean that the package is incompatible but this is common.

For example, `node-sass` (doesn't seem to be used here) has different versions that correspond to specific Node.js versions and provides precompiled binaries for a supported subset; for unsupported Node.js version it falls back to compilation during installation process and most likely fails.

It's unknown which dependency causes this problem in this case, this needs to be reviewed in npm/yarn logs.

In order to avoid this situation, Node version could be matched with old one. Project dependencies need to be freshly installed because node_modules in use has been already tied to currently used Node version.

Comment: Thank you, and thank you likewise for the elaboration! And it seems it's really time I make a shift to Docker or equivalent.

Comment: This is definitely an option for backend Node, especially if it's known to use bins for performance or features, but may be overkill for frontend, I don't remember if something except node-sass (which has been deprecated) gave me troubles like that. You didn't say which Node version you originally used, but it should have been even and LTS, odd version (17) will give instant problems.

Comment: Turns out in the original code version, I did have node-sass, and looks like it had been one of the things I had removed in the trial-error process (it was barely in use, so I removed any place using and then the package) and I had added the modified package.json here. In the fresh repo copy, node-sass is present. But since I had removed node-sass, which got rid of errors, not sure if node-sass was the only reason, but nothing else got errors. Could package-lock.json play a role? I'll try to remove node-sass again and see!

The original node ver. was 14.5.5, thew new one was something 16+.

Comment: Yes, it definitely plays role. If it's in package lock, it's installed. In your case it's probably just needs to be updated to the version that's compatible with 16 , https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy . JS-only `sass` package is a drop-in replacement but may require some adjustments to scss files

Comment: Thank you EstusFlask for the insights! :) It seems various parts of this information is not easy to find nor figure out from the maze of possibilities, without good previous experience. I also realized where in this picture I have lots of reading to do to deepen understanding of what's going on to have a better shot at debugging equivalent problems.

Comment: Yes, you need some Node background for smooth frontend development, at least Webpack and common NPM knowledge.